# Rate of convergence of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X_{0}\sim N(0,1)$, $X_{1}$ another RV independent of $X_{0}$.
Let $X_{t}=(1-t)X_{0}+tX_{1}.$ We know that as $t\to1,$ $\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{t}]\to\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{1}]=E[X_{0}]=0.$
Can we determine the rate of this convergence? For instance, if $X_{1}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2}),$
we [can
compute](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution) everything explicitly so that $\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{t}]=\frac{1-t}{(1-t)^{2}+\sigma^{2}t^{2}}$
and hence $\frac{1}{1-t}(\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{t}]-\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{1}])\to\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$
as $t\to1.$

The question more precisely is, are there some mild assumptions on $X_{1}$ (besides $X_0\perp X_1$)
so that $\frac{1}{1-t}(\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{t}]-\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{1}])$
converges to something finite?

Comments: I tried taking derivative wrt time of $\mathbb{E}[X_{0}|X_{t}]$
but it gets very messy.